# How to hide game's state when going to background

Tags: ios, swift, notificationcenter

I am writing a logic puzzle game in SpriteKit that plays on the iPad and is against the clock, and am struggling to hide the puzzle neatly when the app goes into the background.

The issue is that user shouldn't be able to double-tap on the home button and see the full puzzle in the App Switcher, as this would allow them to work through it without the clock running.

This is the solution I have come up with:

In the Singleton `GameManager` there is a variable that is a `SKTexture()`, to hold a screenshot texture, and in my `AppDelegate` I have:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "resigning"), object: self)
        
    let tempBackground = UIImageView(image: UIImage(cgImage: GameManager.shared.puzzleImage.cgImage()))
    tempBackground.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1024, height: 768)
    tempBackground.tag = 1000
    self.window?.addSubview(tempBackground)
    self.window?.bringSubviewToFront(tempBackground)
}
```

This sends out a notification when it's about to resign the focus, which is picked up by my `GameScene`, which then creates a screenshot and stores it to the variable in my `GameManager`.  This is then added as a `subview` in the `AppDelegate`.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        // Layout puzzle here
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appToBackground), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "resigning") , object: nil)
    }

    @objc private func appToBackground() {
        // Save state of puzzle and hide it
        
        GameManager.shared.puzzleImage = SKView().texture(from: self)!
    }
}
```

This all works.  But not brilliantly.  There is a noticeable time-lag between double-tapping and the `tempBackground` being added - the App Switcher shows the puzzle in detail very briefly and then changes the image to the hidden puzzle.

When the app comes back into focus, the following is called in `AppDelegate`:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if let tempBackground = self.window?.viewWithTag(1000) {
        tempBackground.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

But when the app returns to focus, the `tempBackground` is shown, then there is a very brief glimpse of the puzzle in all its detail, before once again showing the hidden puzzle.

I may well have gone about this completely the wrong way, but after reading various archive questions and articles on the internet, this seemed to be way to go.

What I'd like to know is: is there any way that I can have the hidden puzzle shown in the App Switcher immediately and avoid the flash of puzzle detail when returning to the puzzle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue in adding subview logic, but the issue is in where are you triggering it, as per [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1838/_index.html), you should add subview in `applicationDidEnterBackground` and should remove you subview and prepare your app to display in `applicationWillEnterForeground`

As I have created Xcode project in Xcode 12, my project has scene delegate, here is the code I used and O/P is shown in gif below

```
    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        guard let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HiddenView", owner: nil, options: [:])?[0] as? HiddenView else { return }
        view.tag = 1000
        view.frame = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].frame
        UIApplication.shared.windows[0].addSubview(view)
        UIApplication.shared.windows[0].bringSubviewToFront(view)
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        if let tempBackground = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].viewWithTag(1000) {
            tempBackground.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

As OP has mentioned, that he is not using Scene Delegate I am updating the answer for `AppDelegate`

```
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        guard let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HiddenView", owner: nil, options: [:])?[0] as? HiddenView else { return }
        view.tag = 1000
        view.frame = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].frame
        UIApplication.shared.windows[0].addSubview(view)
        UIApplication.shared.windows[0].bringSubviewToFront(view)
    }
    
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        if let tempBackground = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].viewWithTag(1000) {
            tempBackground.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, @Sandeep, but when I move the code to the functions you mention, I don't get the tempBackground showing at all, I get the puzzle in all its detail.

Comment: @gbasher: Strange, lemme check

Comment: Thanks for responding, but unfortunately, my app isn't using SceneDelegate so I'm searching for an answer without using Scenes - it's a SpriteKit game.  The problem is also with the double-tap of the home button from within the game, not the single tap as you're doing in your solution.

Comment: @gbasher: I can guarantee you that even on double tap, view is being hidden and my hidden label shows up, delegate am using it is `sceneWillResignActive` which will get called no matter if you single / double tap

Comment: Sandeep - many thanks for your efforts, but sadly my problem still persists.  I have, however, narrowed it down to the fact that when removing the tempBackground (upon returning focus to the app), the app reverts to the screenshot it took when I first double-tap the home button - hence the brief glimpse of the puzzle detail.  Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: @gbasher: This might have something to do with your code in `class GameScene: SKScene ` please comment `didMove(to view: SKView) {` and `appToBackground() {` logic otherwise I dont see any other issue if you simply use `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` delegates as is

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, although it feels more like a work-around than a proper solution.

The problem is that iOS takes a snapshot of the screen before sending the app into the background and uses this when the app returns to the foreground.

This snapshot can be replaced by using either a predefined view (see @Sandeep's solution) or creating a new snapshot of the screen once the puzzle has been hidden (my original attempted solution).

However, removing this dummy in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` means that the original snapshot taken by the iOS is shown briefly before updating the screen.

There is a function `UIApplication.shared.ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch()` which can be entered into the `applicationWillResignActive()` function, but it doesn't seem to be working all the time - just most of it.  In fact, on the Apple Developer's forum there's a comment about how it's inconsistent and a bug was reported.  But that was over a year ago and it's still inconsistent.

Instead, in this function add the dummy not to the `self.window?` directly, but to the view of the `rootViewController`, using
`self.window?.rootViewController!.view.addSubview(dummyImage)`

Then don't actually remove this when the app comes back into the foreground.  Instead, use `Notification` to alert `GameScene` that the app is back in the foreground.  This can then run a method which adds a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the scene.  This in turn can be linked to a method that fades out the dummy image, before removing both it and the `UITapGestureRecognizer` once it's completed.

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but it seems to work.